# Web application could not be started undefined method

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, redmine

When I installed redmine-3.3 & 3.4 , I am not getting redmine page 
I am facing this Error

```
Web application could not be started
undefined method `require_sudo_mode' for EmailAddressesController:Class (NoMethodError)
  /usr/share/redmine/app/controllers/email_addresses_controller.rb:21:in `<class:EmailAddressesController>'  
  /usr/share/redmine/app/controllers/email_addresses_controller.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:444:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:443:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:443:in `block in eager_load!'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:441:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:441:in `eager_load!'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'  
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'  
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'  
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'  
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'  
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'  
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
Application root /usr/share/redmine Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV) production Ruby interpreter
command /usr/bin/ruby.. .... ..
```

Can you give me suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to this [issue on Redmine.org](https://www.redmine.org/issues/24831)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you'r connected with your database and did you missing any required gem.

require_sudo_mode. If the error comes because of this you definitely missing this gem.

This type of error comes under database not connected issue.If you are fix that this would be start.Thanks..!

Comment: `require_sudo_mode` is not a gem but a method provided by Redmine. It has nothing to do with a failed database connection. Instead, it is (as @spickermann correctly identified) a reported Redmine issue which might be caused by certain environment conditions.